# Organizing a gallery of Images into 2 columns, 4 images per line

Tags: html, css

I am stuck on how to arrange images for my gallery.php page so that there are 4 images per line. My first thought was to use 2 divs, one as column 1 and one as column 2, and then have two spans inside the divs labeled left and right, and float the span left float left, and the other span right. I made sure two make the widths of each of the column divs 50% and each image width 25% however it still did not work.

Here is the HTML portion of my code, and below the HTML is CSS.

```
     <p id="service">Gallery of Completed Sabers</p>
<div class="col1">  
    <span class="left">
    <img src="images/corran.jpg" alt="Corran Horn" />
    <p>GCS:Corran Horn</p></span>
    <span class="right">
    <img src="images/corran.jpg" alt="Corran Horn" />
    <p>GCS:Corran Horn</p></span>

    </div>
    <div class="col2">  
    <span class="left">
    <img src="images/corran.jpg" alt="Corran Horn" />
    <p>GCS:Corran Horn</p></span>
    <span class="right">
    <img src="images/corran.jpg" alt="Corran Horn" />
    <p>GCS:Corran Horn</p></span>

    </div>
```

CSS

```
    div.col1 {
width:50%;
}
div.col2 {
    width:50%;
}

span.left {
    float:left;;
}
span.right {
    float:right;
}   

img {
    width: 25%;
}
```

I am going to keep messing around, and see, maybe I will try 4 different columns.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
    <section class="column">
    <div class="image-container">
        <img src="https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/128626743/disp/bdf7c7afb76e0a0866cea43416c4b555.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
        <img src="https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/128626743/disp/bdf7c7afb76e0a0866cea43416c4b555.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
        <img src="https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/128626743/disp/bdf7c7afb76e0a0866cea43416c4b555.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
        <img src="https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/128626743/disp/bdf7c7afb76e0a0866cea43416c4b555.jpg">
    </div>

</section>

<section class="column">
    <div class="image-container">
        <img src="https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/128626743/disp/bdf7c7afb76e0a0866cea43416c4b555.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
        <img src="https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/128626743/disp/bdf7c7afb76e0a0866cea43416c4b555.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
        <img src="https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/128626743/disp/bdf7c7afb76e0a0866cea43416c4b555.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
        <img src="https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/128626743/disp/bdf7c7afb76e0a0866cea43416c4b555.jpg">
    </div>

</section>


*{
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

.column{
width:100%;
min-height:200px;
background:red;
border-bottom:1px solid blue;
}

.image-container{
width: 25%;
height: 200px;
float: left;
}

.image-container img{
max-height: 200px;
width: 100%;
}
```